# How can I get a background image and game objects to fill black areas of letterbox or pillarbox?

Tags: unity

I have used the [Aspect Ratio Enforcer](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=AspectRatioEnforcer#Usage_with_OnGUI) to force my game's aspect ratio to remain as 9:16. I need to prevent some game objects and the backgrounds from being affected by the enforced aspect ratio to cover the black areas that result from other aspect ratios.
How can I prevent some game objects and background images from getting affecting by the Aspect Ratio Enforcer?